# Why is d3.select not working with html button

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have an animated D3 line graph that I am trying to trigger with buttons. When I try and set the buttons to trigger nothing happens. However with out the buttons it works fine.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Codepen is here here if you are interested: https://codepen.io/MrVincentRyan/pen/xmZeyw

```js
d3.select("#start").on("click", function() {
  var path = svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

  // Variable to Hold Total Length
  var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

  // Set Properties of Dash Array and Dash Offset and initiate Transition
  path
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
    .transition() // Call Transition Method
    .duration(4000) // Set Duration timing (ms)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear) // Set Easing option
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0); // Set final value of dash-offset for transition
});

// Reset Animation
d3.select("#reset").on("click", function() {
  d3.select(".line").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">Start Time Animation</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `.datum(data)` to `.datum(dataset)`

```
 d3.select("#start").on("click", function() {
        var path = svg.append("path")
            .datum(dataset) // Changes Here
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/roxENw

or also remove `script` tag after the button your codepen HTML